# How to extract a string before and after slash

Tags: r, regex

I am working on Parts of Speech tagging in R. I have a string with its Parts of Speech as below(Format: Word/POS_Tag). I want to extract words in one column and its corresponding Parts of Speech tag in other column and it frequency in 3rd column of a dataset.
Also, I need to remove any punctuation or special characters from the text before loading into dataset. I am not much familiar with RegEx. Can you please help me to resolve this.

(FYR. Sentence before applying POS_tag. --> "I like to play tennis tournament Next week, and I will participate on a play. I like playing guitar.")

Example: `"I/PRP like/IN to/TO play/VB tennis/NN tournament/NN Next/JJ week/NN ,/, and/CC I/PRP will/MD participate/VB on/IN a/DT play/NN ./. I/PRP like/IN playing/VBG guitar/NN ./."`

Note: In the above example, we have 3 occurrences of 'I' and 2 occurrences of 'like'. I need the count of words as well as below in a dataset.

```
Word           POS_Tag    Count
I              PRP        3
like           IN         2
to             TO         1
play           VB         1
tennis         NN         1
tournament     NN         1
Next           JJ         1
week           NN         1
and            CC         1
will           MD         1
partcipate     VB         1
on             IN         1
a              DT         1
play           NN         1
playing        VBG        1
guitar         NN         1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We extract the words (`\\w+`) from the string with `str_extract_all` (from `stringr`), then create a `data.table` with two columns from the alternate words of the `vector` ('v1'), grouped by 'Word', and 'POS_Tag', get the number of elements (`.N`)

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
v1 <- str_extract_all(str1, "\\w+")[[1]]
data.table(Word = v1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], POS_Tag = v1[c(FALSE, TRUE)])[
    , .(Count = .N), .(Word, POS_Tag)]
#           Word POS_Tag Count
# 1:           I     PRP     3
# 2:        like      IN     2
# 3:          to      TO     1
# 4:        play      VB     1
# 5:      tennis      NN     1
# 6:  tournament      NN     1
# 7:        Next      JJ     1
# 8:        week      NN     1
# 9:         and      CC     1
#10:        will      MD     1
#11: participate      VB     1
#12:          on      IN     1
#13:           a      DT     1
#14:        play      NN     1
#15:     playing     VBG     1
#16:      guitar      NN     1
```

---

We can also do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(string = str1) %>%
       separate_rows(string) %>% 
       group_by(grp = rep(c("Word", "POS_Tag"), length.out = n())) %>% 
       mutate(i1 = row_number()) %>%
       spread(grp, string) %>% select(-i1) %>% 
       count(Word, POS_Tag) %>%
       filter(Word != ".")
# A tibble: 16 x 3
#          Word POS_Tag     n
#         <chr>   <chr> <int>
# 1           a      DT     1
# 2         and      CC     1
# 3      guitar      NN     1
# 4           I     PRP     3
# 5        like      IN     2
# 6        Next      JJ     1
# 7          on      IN     1
# 8 participate      VB     1
# 9        play      NN     1
#10        play      VB     1
#11     playing     VBG     1
#12      tennis      NN     1
#13          to      TO     1
#14  tournament      NN     1
#15        week      NN     1
#16        will      MD     1
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "I/PRP like/IN to/TO play/VB tennis/NN tournament/NN Next/JJ week/NN ,/, and/CC I/PRP will/MD participate/VB on/IN a/DT play/NN ./. I/PRP like/IN playing/VBG guitar/NN ./."
```

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun. This helped me a lot!! :)

Comment: Hi akrun, I am facing some difficulties in this solution for the following example. "I/PRP did/VBD n't/RB experienced/VBN much/JJ service/NN differentiation/NN". The result is not coming as expected because of having apostrophe in "n't". Is there any solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: @ParthasarathyBalaraman  Could you please post as a new question

Comment: Posted as a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456676/how-to-extract-a-string-using-regex-for-pos-tagging-in-r