# How to extract a string using Regex for POS Tagging

Tags: r, regex

With reference to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434739/how-to-extract-a-string-before-and-after-slash-in-r), I am facing some difficulties in that solution for the following example.

```
 "I/PRP did/VBD n't/RB experienced/VBN much/JJ service/NN differentiation/NN" The/DT desktop/NN and/CC CAD/NN support/NN is/VBZ working/VBG as/IN expected/VBN CAD-support/NNP Desktop/NNP management/NN related/VBD to/TO LSB/NNP Desktop/NNP management/NN team/NN is/VBZ very/RB committed/VBN ./."
```

The result is not coming as expected because of having apostrophe in "n't" and hyphen "CAD-Support". I am posting this as a new query as requested. Can anyone help me to resolve this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the previous solution, all you need to change is the regex to

```
[^\s/]+
```

in code:

```
str_extract_all(str1, "[^\\s/]+")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KTaONV/1).

It will match 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `/`.

To avoid matching `./.`, you'll need to use something like

```
\w+(?:['-]\w+)*
```

in code:

```
str_extract_all(str1, "\\w+(?:['-]\\w+)*")
```

that will match 1+ word chars followed with 0+ sequences of `'` or `-` followed with 1+ word chars. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KWcce7/1).